# In Google Analytics, how to get acquisition data for a given landing page?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to know how people are finding out about a given landing page. Is that possible?

The best I could do now is to browse all acquisition data looking for possible entry points, e.g. clicking on referral websites and looking at the search engine optimization data, but it's not very practical as I have to go through data for all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly - You are looking for data that will show you how users first got to your site, and through which page.

You can go to Behavior-->Site Content-->Landing pages, and then add "Source/Medium" as the Secondary dimension.
This will make sure that the content you see is the first entry point to your site.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the possibility of adding the second dimension. If I do that, and then sort by the landing page, it gives me what I want.